# Depth First Backtracking Puzzle Solver

Tags: python, game, python-3.x, depth-first-search, backtracking

There is this type of puzzle

[image: Turtel puzzle cards]

that can easily be solved with a depth-first backtracking solver. I wrote one in python 3.4 and like to get some feedback.

I'm especially interested in the following points:

- `deepcopy`. The usage of `deepcopy` in `DepthFirstBacktrackingSolver.findsolutions` is somewhat ugly. As Python simply binds objects to identifies I need to request a copy a of solution, otherwise the solution would be overwritten when the next solution is constructed. Is the `deepcopy` really necessary?
- `copy`. The usage of `copy` in `DepthFirstBacktrackingSolver.findsolutions` is ugly too. I could avoid the `copy` by temporarily removing the card from the list of available cards for the rest of this search tree branch:

  ```
  unusedcards.remove(card)  # remove the card we just placed from the list
  solution.extend(self.findsolutions(assignment, unusedcards))
  unusedcards.append(card)  # reappend the card to explore other solutions
  ```
- Exploiting symmetry. Every solution can be rotated and three more solutions are obtained. I haven’t found a good way to exploit the symmetry in this type of game. Especially with larger boards 5x5, 6x6, 7x7, 8x8, ... the possible savings in pruning the 
  search tree should be worth incorporating this.
- And all else that you can spot.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from copy import copy
from enum import Enum


class HeadTail(Enum):
    head = 1
    tail = 2


class Color(Enum):
    brown = 1
    orange = 2
    green = 3
    blue = 4
    red = 5
    grey = 6
    yellow = 7


class SymbolHalf(object):
    """One half of a symbol."""

    def __init__(self, ht, color) -> None:
        self.__ht = ht
        self.__color = color

    @property
    def ht(self):
        return self.__ht

    @property
    def farbe(self):
        return self.__color

    def ismatching(self, other: 'SymbolHalf') -> bool:
        """
        :param other: another symbol half
        :return: true when both symbol halfs match, false otherwise
        """
        result = False
        if self.__color == other.__color:
            if (self.__ht == HeadTail.head and other.__ht == HeadTail.tail) or \
               (self.__ht == HeadTail.tail and other.__ht == HeadTail.head):
                result = True
        return result

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{0.ht!s} {0.color!s}".format(self)

    def __eq__(self, other: 'SymbolHalf') -> bool:
        """
        two symbol halfs are equal when the attributes agree.
        :param other: the other symbol half to compare against
        """
        return self.__ht == other.__ht and self.__color == other.__color

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "SymbolHalf({0.ht!r}, {0.color!r})".format(self)


class Card(object):
    """A card of a puzzle carries four symbol halfs."""

    def __init__(self, nr: int, n: SymbolHalf, w: SymbolHalf, s: SymbolHalf, o: SymbolHalf) -> None:
        """
        :param int nr: number of the card
        :param SymbolHalf n: northern symbol half
        :param SymbolHalf s: southern symbol half
        :param SymbolHalf w: western symbol half
        :param SymbolHalf o: eastern symbol half
        """
        assert isinstance(nr, int)
        self.nr = nr
        self.__symbole = [n, o, s, w]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.nr)

    def __getsymbolhalf(self, position: int, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        """
        get the symbol half in 'position' of the card accounting for the rotation 'alpha' of the card.
        :param int position: cardinal direction
        :param int alpha: rotation angle of the card 0 90 180 270
        :return: the requested symbol half
        """
        return self.__symbole[(alpha // 90 + position) % 4]

    def north(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(0, alpha)

    def east(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(1, alpha)

    def south(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(2, alpha)

    def west(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(3, alpha)


class NoEmptyFieldFound(Exception):
    pass


class CardAssignment(object):
    """Assignment of cards on the NxN field."""

    def __init__(self, n: int=3) -> None:
        """
        :param int n: edge length of the square field
        """
        self.fields = [[[None, 0] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        temp = '| '
        for row in self.fields:
            for field in row:
                temp += '{} {}  '.format(field[0], field[1] // 90)  # number of the card and number of left turns
            temp += '|  '
        return temp

    def __getcoordinates(self, fieldnr: int):
        """
        convert the field number in the row and column index
        :param int fieldnr: the number of the field 0..n**2-1
        """
        rowlength = len(self.fields)
        assert fieldnr <= rowlength ** 2, 'Field number too high'
        rowindex = fieldnr // rowlength
        columnindex = fieldnr % rowlength
        return rowindex, columnindex

    def __getalpha(self, fieldnr: int) -> int:
        rowindex, columnindex = self.__getcoordinates(fieldnr)
        return self.fields[rowindex][columnindex][1]

    def __getcard(self, fieldnr: int) -> Card:
        rowindex, columninxex = self.__getcoordinates(fieldnr)
        return self.fields[rowindex][columninxex][0]

    def place(self, card: Card, alpha: int, fieldnr: int) -> None:
        """
        place the 'card' on field with the given number.
        :param Card card: the card to be placed
        :param int fieldnr: the number of the field
        """
        rowindex, columnindex = self.__getcoordinates(fieldnr)
        self.fields[rowindex][columnindex][0] = card
        self.fields[rowindex][columnindex][1] = alpha

    def clear(self, fieldnr: int):
        """
        remove the card from the field
        :param int fieldnr: number of the field
        """
        rowindex, columnindex = self.__getcoordinates(fieldnr)
        self.fields[rowindex][columnindex][0] = None
        self.fields[rowindex][columnindex][1] = 0

    def isoccupied(self, fieldnr: int) -> bool:
        """
        checks wether the given field is occupied by a card.
        :param int fieldnr: number of the field
        """
        rowindex, columnindex = self.__getcoordinates(fieldnr)
        return not (self.fields[rowindex][columnindex][0] is None)

    def isfull(self) -> bool:
        """
        checks if there is an empty field left
        :return: true if all fields are occupied, false otherwise
        """
        emptyfieldfound = False
        for row in self.fields:
            for field in row:
                if field[0] is None:
                    emptyfieldfound = True
        return not emptyfieldfound

    def findnextfreefield(self) -> int:
        """
        finds the next free field in row major order
        :return: the number of the field
        """
        for nr in range(len(self.fields) ** 2):
            if not self.isoccupied(nr):
                return nr
        raise NoEmptyFieldFound

    def ismatching(self, card: Card, alpha: int, fieldnr: int) -> bool:
        """
        checks if the 'card' can be placed on the field with number 'fieldnr'
        as we proceed in row major order across the field we only have to check,
        if the smybols across the western and northern edge match.
        """
        rowlength = len(self.fields)
        assert fieldnr <= rowlength ** 2, 'Field number too high'
        assert isinstance(card, Card), 'object of class Card expected'

        def issamerow(fieldnr1: int, fieldnr2: int) -> bool:
            return (fieldnr1 // rowlength) == (fieldnr2 // rowlength)

        cardmatchesnorth = cardmatcheswest = True
        northernneighbour = fieldnr - rowlength  # the adjacent field in northern direction has a field number -n
        if northernneighbour >= 0:  # check for the border
            if self.isoccupied(northernneighbour):
                other = self.__getcard(northernneighbour)
                cardmatchesnorth = card.north(alpha).ismatching(other.south(self.__getalpha(northernneighbour)))

        westernneighbour = fieldnr - 1  # the adjacent field in western dierection has a field number -1
        if westernneighbour >= 0 and issamerow(fieldnr, westernneighbour):  # check border
            if self.isoccupied(westernneighbour):
                other = self.__getcard(westernneighbour)
                cardmatcheswest = card.west(alpha).ismatching(other.east(self.__getalpha(westernneighbour)))

        return cardmatchesnorth and cardmatcheswest


class DepthFirstBacktrackingSolver(object):
    """
    Solve puzzels per depth-first backtracking
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.solutions = []

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        temp = ''
        for s in self.solutions:
            temp += str(s)
        return temp

    def findsolutions(self, assignment: CardAssignment, unusedcards: list) -> list:
        """
        take a partial assignment and try to add one more card from the list of free cards to it
        recursively walk the game tree depth first until a complete solution is found
        :param CardAssignment assignment: current assignment of cards on the field
        :param list unusedcards: list of unused cards
        :return list: list of the solutions
        """
        assert isinstance(assignment, CardAssignment), 'object of class CardAssignment expectd'
        assert isinstance(unusedcards, list), 'object of class list expected'
        solution = []
        freefieldnr = assignment.findnextfreefield()
        for card in unusedcards:  # try every card
            for alpha in [0, 90, 180, 270]:  # in all possible positions
                if assignment.ismatching(card, alpha, freefieldnr):
                    assignment.place(card, alpha, freefieldnr)
                    if assignment.isfull():  # as we only place a card when it matches, a full field is a solution
                        solution.append(deepcopy(assignment))
                    else:
                        remainingcards = copy(unusedcards)
                        remainingcards.remove(card)  # remove the card we just placed from the list
                        solution.extend(self.findsolutions(assignment, remainingcards))
                    assignment.clear(freefieldnr)  # clear the field to continue the search for the other solutions
        return solution

# north west south east
Turtelcards = [Card(1, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown)),
               Card(2, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.brown), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.green)),
               Card(3, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange)),
               Card(4, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown)),
               Card(5, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.brown), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange)),
               Card(6, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown)),
               Card(7, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.brown), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange)),
               Card(8, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown)),
               Card(9, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown))
]


def main():
    solver = DepthFirstBacktrackingSolver()
    emptyassignment = CardAssignment()
    solutions = solver.findsolutions(emptyassignment, Turtelcards)
    for solution in solutions:
        print(solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Now, I'm really not a fan of comments on the end of lines, so I'd fix that all up. You're also using `everythingisonewordcase` instead of `snake_case`; the convention is strongly towards the latter.

Since this is Python 3, you don't need to inherit from `object`, but... `DepthFirstBacktrackingSolver` is just a function, albeit one that pretends to be more. Well, don't let it! All it's done is give you unused state and a broken unused `__str__` method.

```
def find_solutions(assignment: CardAssignment, unused_cards: list) -> list:
    # Same as before
```

Then I suggest making it `yield` its solutions:

```
def find_solutions(assignment: CardAssignment, unused_cards: list) -> list:
    """..."""
    assert isinstance(assignment, CardAssignment), 'object of class CardAssignment expected'
    assert isinstance(unused_cards, list), 'object of class list expected'

    free_field_nr = assignment.find_next_free_field()
    # try every card
    for card in unused_cards:
        # in all possible positions
        for alpha in [0, 90, 180, 270]:
            if assignment.is_matching(card, alpha, free_field_nr):
                assignment.place(card, alpha, free_field_nr)
                # as we only place a card when it matches, a full field is a solution
                if assignment.is_full():
                    yield deepcopy(assignment)
                else:
                    remaining_cards = copy(unused_cards)
                    # remove the card we just placed from the list
                    remaining_cards.remove(card)
                    yield from find_solutions(assignment, remaining_cards)
                # clear the field to continue the search for the other solutions
                assignment.clear(free_field_nr)
```

Now, your docstring is covered in implementation details. It should instead read more like

```
Take a partial assignment and find complete assignments from the unused_cards list.
Yield each solution.

:param CardAssignment assignment: current assignment of cards on the field
:param list unused_cards: unused cards
:return generator: iterator of solutions
```

Going through the logic, we have

```
free_field_nr = assignment.find_next_free_field()
```

This seems a little unneeded - you can just increment this value each time you recurse.

You then do

```
for card in unused_cards:
    for alpha in [0, 90, 180, 270]:
```

This seems suboptimal:

- You're iterating over a list instead of a tuple
- The possibilities (0, 90, etc.) are sparse
- The type is far too large; almost all numbers are invalid rotations

Much simpler would be

```
for card in unused_cards:
    for oriented_card in card.orientations():
```

This removes the fiddling with rotations altogether. Further, it means that the functions you pass it to only need to take an oriented card, which can be a different type. So let's look at the card type.

```
class Card:
    """A card of a puzzle carries four symbol halfs."""

    def __init__(self, nr: int, n: SymbolHalf, w: SymbolHalf, s: SymbolHalf, o: SymbolHalf) -> None:
        """
        :param int nr: number of the card
        :param SymbolHalf n: northern symbol half
        :param SymbolHalf s: southern symbol half
        :param SymbolHalf w: western symbol half
        :param SymbolHalf o: eastern symbol half
        """
        assert isinstance(nr, int)
        self.nr = nr
        self.__symbole = [n, o, s, w]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.nr)

    def __getsymbolhalf(self, position: int, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        """
        get the symbol half in 'position' of the card accounting for the rotation 'alpha' of the card.
        :param int position: cardinal direction
        :param int alpha: rotation angle of the card 0 90 180 270
        :return: the requested symbol half
        """
        return self.__symbole[(alpha // 90 + position) % 4]

    def north(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(0, alpha)

    def east(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(1, alpha)

    def south(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(2, alpha)

    def west(self, alpha: int) -> SymbolHalf:
        return self.__getsymbolhalf(3, alpha)
```

Don't use `__mangled` names; just use `_private` names unless you *really* need name mangling (which you should try and avoid).

Your `__str__` is also misleading. If you wish to do something like this, just print `.nr` directly. Otherwise a `Card` looks like a number, which is a pain for debugging.

Your `_getsymbolhalf` does a lot of work we're going to try and avoid, so lets work out a better way of doing this.

```
from collections import deque, namedtuple

OrientedCard = namedtuple("OrientedCard", ["id", "orientation", "north", "east", "south", "west"])

class Card:
    def __init__(self, id: int, *sides):
        if len(sides) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Cards have exactly 4 sides, expected 4 arguments")

        self.id = id
        self.sides = sides

    def orientations(self):
        sides_rot = deque(self.sides)

        for i in range(4):
            yield OrientedCard(self.id, i, *sides_rot)
            sides_rot.rotate(1)
```

The `orientation` is stored here for printing.

`SymbolHalf` similarly seems like it could be reduced to a `namedtuple`:

```
class SymbolHalf(namedtuple("SymbolHalfFields", ["body_half", "color"])):
    __slots__ = ()

    def matches(self, other: 'SymbolHalf') -> bool:
        """
        :param SymbolHalf other:
        :return: Whether the symbols are two halves of the same turtle
        """
        return self.color == other.color and self.body_half != other.body_half
```

`__slots__ = ()` is useful when inheriting from `namedtuple` since having a `__dict__` breaks some `namedtuple` methods.

Back to `find_solutions`, we have

```
if assignment.is_matching(oriented_card, field_num):
```

`is_matching` seems like the wrong question here; it's more like `could_accept`. In it, you have

```
def could_accept(self, card: OrientedCard, field_num: int) -> bool:
    """
    checks if the 'card' can be placed on the field with number 'field_num'
    as we proceed in row major order across the field we only have to check,
    if the smybols across the western and northern edge match.
    """
    rowlength = len(self.fields)
    assert field_num <= rowlength ** 2, 'Field number too high'
    assert isinstance(card, OrientedCard), 'object of class OrientedCard expected'

    def issamerow(fieldnr1: int, fieldnr2: int) -> bool:
        return (fieldnr1 // rowlength) == (fieldnr2 // rowlength)

    card_matches_north = card_matches_west = True
    # the adjacent field in northern direction has a field number -n
    northern_neighbour = field_num - rowlength 
    # check for the border
    if northern_neighbour >= 0:
        if self.is_occupied(northern_neighbour):
            other = self._get_card(northern_neighbour)
            card_matches_north = card.north.matches(other.south)

    # the adjacent field in western dierection has a field number -1
    western_neighbour = field_num - 1
    # check border
    if western_neighbour >= 0 and issamerow(field_num, western_neighbour):
        if self.is_occupied(western_neighbour):
            other = self._get_card(western_neighbour)
            card_matches_west = card.west.matches(other.east)

    return card_matches_north and card_matches_west
```

I don't like the idea that you're decoding and re-encoding the position into a single number. I also don't like the assumption that the board is square; it seems like a rather pointless and unhelpful one. Those `is_occupied` checks are probably wrong, too.

So lets try to fix that up and make this class a bit comfier. First, cache the width and height

```
def __init__(self, width: int=3, height: int=3) -> None:
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.fields = [[None] * height for _ in range(width)]
```

Make a cannonical way to decode:

```
def position_of_num(field_num: int):
    if field_num > self.width * self.height:
        raise ValueError("Field value too large")

    return field_num // self.width, field_num % self.width
```

(this is your `_get_coordinates` but simpler and for public use).

We make a simpler `is_full`:

```
def is_full(self) -> bool:
    """
    :return: whether there is no unfilled field in the grid
    """
    return not any(None in col for col in self.fields)
```

Then make `could_accept` take an `x` and `y` instead:

```
def could_accept(self, card: OrientedCard, x: int, y: int) -> bool:
    """
    Return whether the card can be placed at the given position.
    """
    if not (0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height):
        raise IndexError("Index out of bounds")

    assert isinstance(card, OrientedCard), 'object of class OrientedCard expected'

    if x and not card.north.matches(self.fields[x - 1][y].south):
        return False

    if y and not card.west.matches(self.fields[x][y - 1].east):
        return False

    return True
```

That's all you really need from this.

`could_accept` is fundementally *wrong*, though, since `could_accept` assumes a given iteration order. But classes should be distinct from the algorithms that use them, so it makes sense to me for this to be a local function of some kind. I'd also remove the index check since it'd be thrown for you once you actually try to index, but YMMV.

The `is_full` checks are redundant since you know that it's full only when you've used all the unused cards.

You do

```
unused_cards = copy(unused_cards)
# remove the card we just placed from the list
unused_cards.remove(card)
yield from find_solutions(assignment, unused_cards, field_num+1)
```

traditionally one does

```
unused_cards.remove(card)
yield from find_solutions(assignment, unused_cards, field_num+1)
unused_cards.add(card)
```

because this is much faster. However, this doesn't work if you're iterating over the values at the same time. The simplest nicer solution I see would be to use a set and do

```
# If len(unused_cards) > 1, we've got more cards to place
if len(unused_cards) > 1:
    yield from find_solutions(assignment, unused_cards - {card}, field_num+1)
else:
    yield deepcopy(assignment)
```

It is possible to avoid this by doing more intelligent work (such as maksing values), but since we search the whole tree this doesn't actually help much.

`TurtelCards` currently looks like

```
Turtelcards = {Card(1, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown)),
               Card(2, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.brown), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.green)),
               Card(3, SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.brown), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.green), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.head, Color.blue), SymbolHalf(HeadTail.tail, Color.orange)),
               # ...
}
```

I think it's much easier to read as

```
def make_symbol_half(string):
    part, color = string.split()
    return SymbolHalf(HeadTail.__members__[part], Color.__members__[color])

def make_card(card_id, *symbols):
    return Card(card_id, *map(make_symbol_half, symbols))

Turtelcards = {
    make_card(1, 'tail green',  'head orange', 'head blue',  'tail brown'),
    make_card(2, 'tail orange', 'head brown',  'head blue',  'tail green'),
    make_card(3, 'tail brown',  'head green',  'head blue',  'tail orange'),
    make_card(4, 'tail orange', 'head blue',   'head green', 'tail brown'),
    make_card(5, 'tail green',  'head brown',  'head green', 'tail orange'),
    make_card(6, 'tail blue',   'head orange', 'head green', 'tail brown'),
    make_card(7, 'tail blue',   'head brown',  'head green', 'tail orange'),
    make_card(8, 'tail green',  'head orange', 'head blue',  'tail brown'),
    make_card(9, 'tail blue',   'head orange', 'head blue',  'tail brown')
}
```

There's no harm in doing a bit of parsing at the start since it's only run once. These probably shouldn't be module-scoped, though, so I'd put them in `main`.

Now, half of the time seems to be spent iterating over `orientations`, so you should cache these.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, num: int, *sides):
        if len(sides) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Cards have exactly 4 sides, expected 4 arguments")

        self.num = num
        self.sides = sides
        self.orientations = tuple(self._make_orientations())

    def _make_orientations(self):
        sides_rot = deque(self.sides)

        for i in range(4):
            yield OrientedCard(self.num, i, *sides_rot)
            sides_rot.rotate(1)
```

Looking at `CardAssignment`'s `__str__`, we have

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
    temp = '| '
    for col in self.fields:
        for field in col:
            # number of the card and number of left turns
            temp += '{} {}  '.format(field.num, field.rotation) 
        temp += '|  '
    return temp
```

This uses `+=` in a loop, which is \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ and disadvised of. This would better be

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
    def format_col(col):
        return "  ".join("{} {}".format(field.num, field.rotation) for field in col)

    return "|  {}  |".format("  |  ".join(map(format_col, self.fields)))
```

That about finishes it. There are much faster ways to solve this, but they'd all involve larger core changes.

Here's the updated code:

```
from collections import deque, namedtuple
from copy import deepcopy
from enum import Enum


class HeadTail(Enum):
    head = 1
    tail = 2


class Color(Enum):
    brown = 1
    orange = 2
    green = 3
    blue = 4
    red = 5
    grey = 6
    yellow = 7


class SymbolHalf(namedtuple("SymbolHalfFields", ["body_half", "color"])):
    __slots__ = ()

    def matches(self, other: 'SymbolHalf') -> bool:
        """
        :param SymbolHalf other:
        :return: Whether the symbols are two halves of the same turtle
        """
        return self.color == other.color and self.body_half != other.body_half


OrientedCard = namedtuple("OrientedCard", ["num", "rotation", "north", "east", "south", "west"])

class Card:
    def __init__(self, num: int, *sides):
        if len(sides) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Cards have exactly 4 sides, expected 4 arguments")

        self.num = num
        self.sides = sides
        self.orientations = tuple(self._make_orientations())

    def _make_orientations(self):
        sides_rot = deque(self.sides)

        for i in range(4):
            yield OrientedCard(self.num, i, *sides_rot)
            sides_rot.rotate(1)


class CardAssignment:
    """Assignment of cards on the NxM field."""

    def __init__(self, width: int=3, height: int=3) -> None:
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fields = [[None] * height for _ in range(width)]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        def format_col(col):
            return "  ".join("{} {}".format(field.num, field.rotation) for field in col)

        return "|  {}  |".format("  |  ".join(map(format_col, self.fields)))

    def position_of_num(self, field_num: int):
        """Decode field number into an (x, y) tuple."""

        if field_num > self.width * self.height:
            raise ValueError("Field value too large")

        return field_num // self.width, field_num % self.width


def northwest_could_accept(assignment, card: OrientedCard, x: int, y: int) -> bool:
    """
    Return whether the card can be placed at the given position.
    This only checks against northward and westward tiles.
    """
    assert isinstance(card, OrientedCard), 'object of class OrientedCard expected'

    if x and not card.north.matches(assignment.fields[x - 1][y].south):
        return False

    if y and not card.west.matches(assignment.fields[x][y - 1].east):
        return False

    return True


def find_solutions(assignment: CardAssignment, unused_cards: set, field_num: int=0):
    """
    Take a partial assignment and find complete assignments from the unused_cards.
    Yield each solution.

    :param CardAssignment assignment: current assignment of cards on the field
    :param set unused_cards: set of cards to fill the unfilled slots with
    :param int field_num: index of first field number with an empty slot, or earlier
    :return generator: iterator of solutions
    """
    assert isinstance(assignment, CardAssignment), 'object of class CardAssignment expected'
    assert isinstance(unused_cards, set), 'object of class list expected'

    x, y = assignment.position_of_num(field_num)

    # try every card in all possibly positions
    for card in unused_cards:
        for oriented_card in card.orientations:
            if northwest_could_accept(assignment, oriented_card, x, y):
                assignment.fields[x][y] = oriented_card

                # If len(unused_cards) > 1, we've got more cards to place
                if len(unused_cards) > 1:
                    yield from find_solutions(assignment, unused_cards - {card}, field_num+1)
                else:
                    yield deepcopy(assignment)

                # clear the field to continue the search for the other solutions
                assignment.fields[x][y] = None


def main():
    def make_symbol_half(string):
        part, color = string.split()
        return SymbolHalf(HeadTail.__members__[part], Color.__members__[color])

    def make_card(card_id, *symbols):
        return Card(card_id, *map(make_symbol_half, symbols))

    Turtelcards = {
        make_card(1, 'tail green',  'head orange', 'head blue',  'tail brown'),
        make_card(2, 'tail orange', 'head brown',  'head blue',  'tail green'),
        make_card(3, 'tail brown',  'head green',  'head blue',  'tail orange'),
        make_card(4, 'tail orange', 'head blue',   'head green', 'tail brown'),
        make_card(5, 'tail green',  'head brown',  'head green', 'tail orange'),
        make_card(6, 'tail blue',   'head orange', 'head green', 'tail brown'),
        make_card(7, 'tail blue',   'head brown',  'head green', 'tail orange'),
        make_card(8, 'tail green',  'head orange', 'head blue',  'tail brown'),
        make_card(9, 'tail blue',   'head orange', 'head blue',  'tail brown')
    }

    for solution in find_solutions(CardAssignment(), Turtelcards):
        print(solution)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is much appreciated!